# How to stop the kernel from pausing my thread?

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduling, real-time

I have written a software PWM generator for the raspberry PI 4 (Debian Bullseye, kernel 5.10.92). It is a multi-threaded program and one thread is the PWM generator. It is supposed to run uninterrupted and paused at full speed for a correct PWM generation.

It is written in so that it only read/writes to memory. Some of these operations are atomic to communicate with the other threads, and some are directly writing in the registers of the Broadcom chip to toggle the GPIO output.

It works very well and is very fast, except that the thread is interrupted and paused which is of course a problem.

Here are the things that I tried to avoid this problem:

1. Set the thread affinity to CPU 3. Confirmed with top.
2. Set the priority to SCHED_FIFO 99. Confirmed with top.
3. Added the `isolcpus=3` argument to the boot command in `/boot/cmdline.txt`.

Unfortunately, my thread is still paused for a varying duration. I detect it by time measurement and I see it on the GPIO pin with the oscilloscope.

Looking at the [kernel parameter documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt), it is written that isolcpus is deprecated, and replaced by cpuset. But I'm lost since I can't find more info on this.

What do I have to do so that my thread runs at full speed and is not paused by the kernel anymore ?

EDIT: [Source code](https://github.com/chmike/pwmgenerator)

Comment: Do you have the code for whatever you do in that thread? My gut feeling tells me you're not getting interrupted, but just have to wait for something you requested (atomics aren't cheap)
. By the way, using `perf` you can count events like "times a thread was interrupted"

Comment: @MarcusMüller I added a link to the source code. The generator loop is in the file generator.c.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm pretty sure it is a kernel configuration issue because it worked perfectly on another raspberry that was already configured. But it was with Debian Buster 32 bit, not the Bullseye 64bit, and I don't know what changes were made to this device. The problem showed up once I installed the software on a freshly installed device.

Comment: Did you try rt-patched kernel variants, such as Debian's https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/linux-image-5.10.0-10-rt-arm64 ? (I admit even if being supposed to have one core for itself should have been enough)

Comment: @chmike ah, I think I might have found a suspect: you're doing `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW)`, which *might* (on a RPi) mean a context switch. Not sure of that – this is often implemented directly through useland memory mappings.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I also suspected that and comment out all the get time and frequency computation. But the pause are still present. Also, I didn't have this problem with the other device. I suspect I should use cpusets, but I still have to find out how it works.

Comment: I mean, we *can* count the context switches on that CPU, if we care, with stack traces, something like `perf record  -e context-switches -g -c {cpu number you're using for the thread} generator 4000`, or so. `perf record` to show results

Comment: to investigate the lack of vDSO, maybe try using `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` without the `_RAW`. I think that is more widely vDSO'd.